# Enable field when selecting from drop-down box

Tags: javascript

My contact form page, for user edit details, has two drop-down fields, ‘country’ and ‘city’.
I would like when a user is edit his details that the ‘city’ field will be disabled until something is selected in the ‘country’ drop-down menu.

```
<form name="item" action="<?php echo base_url(true) ?>" method="post">

<label><?php _e('Country', 'my_theme'); ?></label>
<?php ItemForm::country_select(get_countries(),user()) ; ?>

<label><?php _e('City', 'my_theme'); ?></label>
<?php ItemForm::cities_select(get_cities(),user()) ; ?>

<button class="itemFormButton" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I’ve tried ‘`onchange`’ in javascript, probably with wrong syntax…

How can I create this? 
Thx.

Comment: You could paste the code where you use `onchange` event, to see why it failed.

Comment: Please remove the php tag from your question. The issue has _nothing_ to do with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/GZ269/. This uses jquery.

```
Country:<br />
<select id="drop1">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="c1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="c2">Country 2</option>
</select>
<br />
City:<br />
<select id="drop2" disabled >
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="c1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="c2">Country 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript function:

```
$("#drop1").change(function(){
    var country = $(this).val();

    if(!country){
        $("#drop2").attr("disabled", true);
        return false;
    }

    $("#drop2").attr("disabled", false);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with Javascript's `onchange` event, and when this event is fired, you have two options:

- Query the cities for the country selected with ajax.

  - This is good if you support (almost) all the countries in the world.
  - Here you must develop a PHP script to be queried when this event is fired.
- Have a great array with the cities for all the countries supported.

  - Too bulky if need you to cover many countries.
  - Less flexible, if you need to add more cities for any country.

Comment: I’ve tried, see above can you help with the correct syntax? thanks,

Comment: Have you? Well, I don't know what `ItemForm` is. But as far as I see, there is no interaction between the country element and the one for the cities.

Comment: There is an interaction between them through linked tables in the same sql db.